# Show names of group by parameter

Tags: pandas, plot

I have a table with teams goals over years.
I want to build trend of depencence of goals during year per each team.

[image]

I'm grouping by team api id:

```
t[t.columns[[1,2,9,10]]].groupby(['team_api_id']).plot(
    kind='bar',figsize=(3,3),x='year_.1',y='sum_goals');
```

How can I get here seen also the team names?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to explicitly loop through each group in the `groupby` as follows:

```
for teamname, group in t.groupby('team_api_id'):
    group.plot(kind='bar',
               figsize=(3,3),
               x='year_.1',
               y='sum_goals',
               title=teamname);
```